# Twig batch function : 2, 3, 2 items

Tags: twig

I'm trying to use `batch()` with TWIG. But I can't find a solution to have a different distribution : `2 items, 3 items, 2 items, 3 items`...

### Example :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

### For the moment I got :

```
{% for row in items|batch(3) %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for column in row %}
            <div class="col">{{ column.content }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**Is there another function with TWIG to do this? Can I have some help please?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that pops in my head is doing the following

```html
{% for values in items|batch(5) %}
    <div class="row">
    {% for value in values[0:2] %}
        <div class="col">{{ value }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    {% for value in values[2:] %}
        <div class="col">{{ value }}</div>
    {% endfor %}    
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/5er8mc)